# Xdvi (or alternatives) and pdfsync

Tags: latex

I am new to ubuntu. I have been using emacs, auctex, and texniscope before on my mac, and I would like to keep using auctex. Is it possible to get pdfsync working with texniscope? Are there any good alternatives with reverse search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try my best to answer your question with possible options to continue to work in the same way you did on the mac in Ubuntu. (Welcome to Ubuntu!)

Texniscope is mac only, but

pdfsync is in the "texlive-latex-extra" package, and auctex is in the repos as well. You can get everything you need with this command:

```
apt-get install auctex texlive-latex-extra
```

As far as a pdf viewer that supports inverse search with pdfsync, the only one I could find in my research was Okular:

http://okular.kde.org/formats.php

You can install it with:

```
apt-get install okular
```

In okular you can set the external editor to be an emacs client.

I'm sorry this isn't exactly step by step, but I hope I got all the pieces together. I don't know enough about latex to know how to glue it into a working workflow. I hope it helps and gets you on your way. (Be sure to be using a recent version of Ubuntu, otherwise the version of okular may not support pdfsync)